# When I Commit certain files under trunk, why revision number is not same for all the files inside that trunk in svn

Tags: svn

When I Commit certain files under trunk, why revision number is not same for all the files inside that trunk in svn. as per SVN the revision number is applied to whole trunk not to individual files.

following is what SVN book said about revisions

Global Revision Numbers
Unlike most version control systems, Subversion's revision numbers apply to the entire repository tree, not individual files.
Each revision number selects an entire tree, a particular state of the repository after some committed change. Another way to
think about it is that revision N represents the state of the repository filesystem after the Nth commit. When Subversion users
talk about “revision 5 of foo.c,” they really mean “foo.c as it appears in revision 5.” Notice that in general, revisions N
and M of a file do not necessarily differ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you commit files, you now have a [mixed-revision working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#idp60853104). Basically, although you *did* create a new revision containing *all* files when you committed your changes, SVN does not automatically retrieve all files from that revision for you when you commit. It only does this when you update. So, to bring your working copy back in sync with an actual revision, you must simply `svn update`.

In fact, it is best practice to always `svn update` before you `svn commit`. Otherwise, changes that build and run fine in your own working copy, may be incompatible with changes made to the rest of the project.

Comment: it was not really about mixed-revision working copy, I have Latest version in my working copy, then I commit to SVN after few file changes, then the revision number change only to committed files, but not to others, so if I see SVN Book they said "Global Revision Numbers" Subversion's revision numbers apply to the entire repository tree, not individual files. So if you help me in understanding this it would be great help. Thanks

Comment: Whenever you commit changes to one or more files, you *automatically* create a mixed revision working copy. That's exactly what you're seeing. The global revision has moved forward. Your working copy does not yet have that global revision. Do an update and you will have that global revision.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the files in repo browser? If so, the revision given for each file there is the revision that file was last updated in.

Comment: Yes, I Know this, but my question was different, When I commit few files in repository, then the revision of other files not changed also should get incremented along with committed files.

Comment: Anywhere you see a revision for an individual file, it's the revision that file was changed in. The revision number of uncommitted files does not change because they weren't edited in that revision. You wouldn't want to see that FileA has revision 12 when it was last edited in revision 5. You would have no way of knowing when FileA was really edited. FileA (rev 5) is still part of rev 12 as a whole.

Comment: Yes, even that was my understanding but when I read in SVN book about "Global Revision Numbers" details posted in my above question, it contradicts our understanding, Is that mean the SVN book description is wrong?, Iam really not getting clear picture.